# Where is the part in code related to the installation on Linux/Mac and windows?

Tags: mac, windows, linux

Where in the [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) is the part related to the GUI and platform depended installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI is based on QT, the code for the GUI is in the folder [`src/qt`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/qt).